# Import modules from subfolders

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I have following arrangement of files:

```
python
|---- main.py
|---- files
      |---- folder1
            |---- a.py, a1.py, ...
      |---- folder2
            |---- b.py, b1.py, ...
```

I wanted to import my modules `a.py` and `b.py` to `main.py`. For this I used the following commands in `main.py`:

```
a = 'C:/python/files/folder1'
sys.path.insert(0, a)
from files.folder1 import *
```

However, I am unable to import modules from folder1 (similarly for folder2).

I get an error:

> No module named files.folder1

I cannot use import command as there are many Python files in folder1, folder2, ...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When I do this in Python 2.7 I use:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/python/files/folder1')

import a
import a1
```

Here's a hack I built to import all modules in a directory into a dictionary:

```
import os
import sys

dir_of_interest = 'C:/python/files/folder1'
modules = {}

sys.path.append(dir_of_interest)
for module in os.listdir(dir_of_interest):
    if '.py' in module and '.pyc' not in module:
        current = module.replace('.py', '')
        modules[current] = __import__(current)
```

I just built it and it's extremely hacky but it might be more like something you want. So, to access the module you want, instead of saying `module_name.thing` you would say `modules["module_name"].thing`

Comment: I agree, however, isn't it cumbersome to write many import statements if you have large number of files?

Comment: @user741592: Why are you splitting your code up between many files?  You should group relevant stuff together into a module.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a requirement to split up the code. I would have been happy to group the chunk into a single file.

Comment: See the above edit/hack... It might be something more like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 32):

Add a file `__init__.py` (can be blank) to folders *files*, *folder1* and *folder2*. Then you got a package *files* with sub-packages *folder1* and *folder2*. After this you can import from the main.py like this:

```
from files.folder1 import *
```

Comment: Nice straightforward answer!

Comment: suppose if my folder structure is like dataaccess.service/services.py, now how to import this path?

Answer (score 3):

> I cannot use import command as there are many Python files in folder1, folder2, ...
>
> What am I missing here?

I believe the part you are missing is the *__init__.py* file in each of the folders.  That file should include an *__all__* variable that lists all the submodules that will imported by: `from somepackage.subpackage import *`.

This is all elegantly explained in the [Python Tutorial section on Packages](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

Comment: The reference link provided really explain it very well.

Answer (score 2):

If you add `folder1` to the path, that doesn't mean you can import `folder1` as a module.  It means you can import the files inside folder1.  So you could do:

```
import a
import a1
```

If you want to have `folder1` be a package of which `a` and `a1` are modules, you need to put an `__init__.py` in `folder1` and then do `import folder1`.  If you further want to be able to do `from folder1 import *` and have that import `a` and `a1`, you need to put code in your `__init__.py` that imports `a` and `a1`.

If you have a lot of files in a folder that you want to be able to import in a structured way, you should make that folder into a package.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the folder structure , what you could do is  , Simply

```
from files.folder1 import a , a1
from files.folder2 import b , b1
```

and this should help

.

Extras :
I recently thought of a problem , of importing pip packages without actually installing them ,
then what i did was ...
i pip installed the package in a virtual environment and copied only folder of the package name

eg. if the package name is qwikidata  , then i went to /Lib folder and copied only the qwikidata folder and pasted it in the root of my project , in your case , where the main.py file is and pip uninstalled the package , to avoid the errors

And now i was able to import the package without actually pip installing it since the package was in my root folder of the project

If the project is not so complicated , then it should be fine , but I wouldn't recommend this way of installing packages .

It helps when you want to run your project on some other machine and You dont have an Internet connection .