# Create object from class in separate file

Tags: python, class, object, package

I have done several tutorials on Python and I know how to define classes, but I don't know how to use them. For example I create the following **file** (car.py):

```
class Car(object):
    condition = 'New'
    def __init__(self,brand,model,color):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.color = color

    def drive(self):
        self.condition = 'Used'
```

Then I create another file (Mercedes.py), where I want to create an object Mercedes from the class Car:

```
Mercedes = Car('Mercedes', 'S Class', 'Red')
```

, but I get an error:

```
NameError: name 'Car' is not defined
```

If I create an instance (object) in the same file where I created it (car), I have no problems:

```
class Car(object):
    condition = 'New'
    def __init__(self,brand,model,color):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.color = color

    def drive(self):
        self.condition = 'Used'

Mercedes = Car('Mercedes', 'S Class', 'Red')

print (Mercedes.color)
```

Which prints:

```
Red
```

So the question is: How can I create an object from a class from different file in the same package (folder)?

Comment: Do you realise that `condition` is a *class attribute*, shared by all instances?

Comment: @jonrsharpe,In order to be separate for each object, I should rename it to self.condition?

Comment: Yes, set it as `self.condition = 'New'` *inside* `__init__`.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

In your `Mercedes.py`, you should import the `car.py` file as follows (as long as the two files are in the *same directory*):

```
import car
```

Then you can do:

```
Mercedes = car.Car('Mercedes', 'S Class', 'Red')  #note the necessary 'car.'
```

Alternatively, you could do

```
from car import Car

Mercedes = Car('Mercedes', 'S Class', 'Red')      #no need of 'car.' anymore
```

Comment: Thanks, I will accept the answer after I am allowed to (in 10 min)

Comment: what if they are _not_ in the same directory? thanks!

Comment: When they are in different directory, you can refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598958/import-modules-from-different-folders/13599005

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the import command in your Mercedes file. 
There's a good intro about importing in Python in [here](https://www.codementor.io/sheena/tutorials/python-path-virtualenv-import-for-beginners-du107r3o1)

Answer (score 1):

Mercedes.py:

```
from car import Car
```

This imports the Car class from car.py
To use it:

```
Mercedes=Car('Mercedes', 'S Class', 'Red')
```