# How to take a calculation from a class and write that into file

Tags: python, file, class

I have an assignment to write a `BMI` class with the following instance variables: `first_name`, `last_name`, `identity_card`, `height`, and `weight`. The I must calculate the BMI value.
I also need to write a program that will read a file into the `BMI` class instances. The program will calculate the BMI value and print all the original data plus the calculated BMI for a new file.

For example, with the file:

```
Yossi Bar 012345678 178 70 
Yuri Gagarin 123456789 157 50
Dana Kama 234567890 160 60
Yona Anerox 345678901 165 43
Dina Dot 456789012 170 80
Rubi Rasmos 567890123 180 100
Rodika Rambam 678901234 170 60
```

My problem is that I can't understand how to add the BMI calculation into the new file.

Here is what I have:

```
class BMI:

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, identity_card, height, weight):
        self._first_name = first_name
        self._last_name = last_name
        self._identity_card = identity_card
        self._height = height
        self._weight = weight

    def GetName(self):
        return self._first_name + " " + self._last_name
    
    def GetID(self):
        return self.identity_card
    
    def GetHeight(self):
        return self.height
    
    def GetWeight(self):
        return self.weight

    def GetBMI(self):
        return (self._weight) / self._height ** 2

def makebmi(infostr):
    first_name, last_name, identity_card, height, weight = infostr.split("\t")
    return BMI(first_name, last_name, identity_card, height, weight)
    
def main(): 
   filename = input("enter the file name: ")
   newfilename = input("enter the new file name: ") 
   with open(filename,'r') as firstfile, open(newfilename,'a') as secondfile: 
    # read content from first file
      for line in firstfile: 
            # append content to second file 
            secondfile.write(line)
           
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238352/create-object-from-class-in-separate-file/23238374
You may get help from here

Comment: It sounds like you have to write the same line as read with some additional data, i.e., `line = '{}\t{}'.format(line, makebmi.GetBMI())`.

Answer (score 0):

I modified ur code a little bit. try it and tell me is that what u wanted.

```
class BMI:

  def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, identity_card, height, weight):
      self._first_name = first_name
      self._last_name = last_name
      self._identity_card = identity_card
      self._height = height
      self._weight = weight

  def GetName(self):
      return self._first_name + " " + self._last_name

  def GetID(self):
      return self.identity_card

  def GetHeight(self):
      return self.height

  def GetWeight(self):
      return self.weight

  def GetBMI(self):
      return round(int(self._weight) / int(self._height) ** 2,3)

def makebmi(infostr):
  first_name, last_name, identity_card, height, weight = infostr.split()
  return BMI(first_name, last_name, identity_card, height, weight)

def main(): 
  filename = input("enter the file name: ")
  newfilename = input("enter the new file name: ") 
  with open(filename,'r') as firstfile, open(newfilename,'a') as secondfile: 
  # read content from first file
    for line in firstfile: 
          # append content to second file 
          secondfile.write(line.rstrip()+" " + str(makebmi(line).GetBMI())+"\n")
       
  if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

or if u want to sort it from largest to smallest bmi.This is one way.

```
class BMI:

  def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, identity_card, height, weight):
    self._first_name = first_name
    self._last_name = last_name
    self._identity_card = identity_card
    self._height = height
    self._weight = weight

  def GetName(self):
    return self._first_name + " " + self._last_name

  def GetID(self):
    return self.identity_card

  def GetHeight(self):
    return self.height

  def GetWeight(self):
    return self.weight

  def GetBMI(self):
    return round(int(self._weight) / int(self._height) ** 2, 3)


def makebmi(infostr):
  first_name, last_name, identity_card, height, weight = infostr.split()
  return BMI(first_name, last_name, identity_card, height, weight)


def main():
  filename = input("enter the file name: ")
  newfilename = input("enter the new file name: ")
  with open(filename, 'r') as firstfile, open(newfilename, 'a') as secondfile:
    # read content from first file
    ls = []
    for line in firstfile:
        # append content to second file
        ls.append(str(makebmi(line).GetBMI()) + "-" + line.rstrip())
    ls.sort(reverse=True)
    for ele in ls:
        secondfile.write(' '.join(ele.split('-')[1:])+" " +ele.split('-')[0]+'\n')
        
if __name__=='__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: thank you so much, i cant believe it's was so easy solution.

Comment: Edited the main answer. please check it.