# Importing a module from another module in python

Tags: python, python-module

I know this question is very common and may be tagged as duplicate, however I have read almost all answers and nothing helps. I am writing this question in desperation. 
My file structures is the following:

```
my_project
|--__init__.py
|--some_file.py
|--module1 
  |--a.py 
  |--__init__.py
|--module2
  |--b.py
  |--__init__.py
```

what I want to do is to import functionality of `a.py` in `b.py` 
I write

```
from module1 import a
```

This throws an error "there is no module named module1"
I am working in python3.7.4

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598958/import-modules-from-different-folders) and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing there is called a relative import, you can read more about them [here](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/). try doing the following.

```
from .module1 import a
```

A relative import specifies the resource to be imported relative to the current location.